# Verify if SNAPSHOT isolation level is on in SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, snapshot-isolation

What SQL will I execute in SSMS for SQL Server 2008 R2 to know if SNAPSHOT isolation level is turned on in the database?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
SELECT snapshot_isolation_state_desc from sys.databases 
where name='<your database name here>'
```

will allow you to check if it is turned on or not.

Comment: Check the is_read_committed_snapshot_on column. When value is 1 it's on.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. Great for all your quick help.